# It is possible to draw a line between each text line?

Tags: html, css, text, line, paragraph

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like this :

The first line…

---

The second line in the same paragraph…

---

The third line…

---

With only one `<p>` ?

Comment: No. See the answers. They involve variations of more than one `<p>` element.

Comment: You can use gradient background. Example you can inspiré yourself from : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGLGNWB

Answer (score -1):

#### Method 1: Use `border-bottom`

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>first line</p>
<p>second line</p>
<p>third line</p>
```

#### Method 2: Use `<hr>` tag

```html
<p>first line</p>
<hr>
<p>second line</p>
<hr>
<p>third line</p>
```

Comment: I meaned between line in a single paragraph, not below the paragraph